# How to save spinner options?

Tags: android, spinner

This is probably a really easy question but Im extremely new to programming..

Could someone please explain to me how to save the answers (using a save button) chosen from several spinners in the SD card, I dont need a database or anything complicated like that. But then I also need a page to be able to see the answers.

So far my code just consists of 5 spinners and their options and thats it - code looks like this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Spinner1.html

Thank you so much!

Comment: oops sorry, Android application, using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You should check out SharedPreferences. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

```
//Saving
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourPreferencesName", 0);
prefs.edit().putString("KeyValue", actual_variable);
prefs.commit();

//Retrieving data
String str = prefs.getString("YourPreferencesName", "DefaultValueIfPrefNotFound");
```

Didn't check the syntax so it might contain errors.

Comment: Thank you J_Andr but Im so new to this I dont actually know what to do with this code, which part is this supposed to go into, is it in the .java part? This is what I have so far: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Spinner1.html (sorry I dont know how to put code here but I copied this exactly and made 5 spinners). Thank you very much!

Comment: You could put it in the item selected listener. I assume all your spinners use the same listener so just remember to use different  preference name in the getString() as a key. Otherwise you'll be just overriding one value.

Comment: Hi, thank you, Im just still not sure what Im doing wrong, here is my code, is this where I need to put it?:      s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    showToast("Question 1: Age =" + "Answer selected");
    
    //Saving
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Save_age", 0);
    prefs.edit().putString("KeyValue", actual_variable);
    prefs.commit();
    
   }

Comment: Looks like a good place to me. Just get the variable from the spinner and save it. Are you getting any errors? Can you print out the value you want in the listener? If so, you are pretty much home free then.